# Reading a specific product from an xml file of products

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <id>246</id>
        <code>Ash07-001</code>
        <image>C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\Ash07-001tmb.jpg</image>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>247</id>
        <code>Ash07-004</code>
        <image>C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\NoBowltmb.jpg</image>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>248</id>
        <code>Ash07-005</code>
        <image>C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\Ash07-005tmb.jpg</image>
    </product>
</products>
```

And read it with this code:

```
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
          document.write("<tr><td>");
          document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("</td><td>");
          document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("</td><td>");
          document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

And that works to get all of the file.

What if I only want the product with the id of 247? How do I pull that entire product out and print just that one?

Comment: /products/product[id='247'] you should really read upon xpath in wc3schools.com

Comment: @user845279: you should avoid [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) at all costs.

Comment: @muistooshort haha, why? It makes it so much easier (it's like wikipedia).

Comment: @user845279: That site is full of nonsense and half truths, they have nothing at all to do with the real W3, they're just gaming Google and trying to sell useless certifications.

Comment: I got the original code from them, but couldn't find code to get the specific product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
          if(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue != 247) continue;
          document.write("<tr><td>");
          document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("</td><td>");
          document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("</td><td>");
          document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
```

You can write code like this . It will not execute code for displaying the content if the id is not 247

Comment: I tried something like that but it didn't work...this does. It's been a long time since I wrote an javascript...thanks to you and to Til86 - I'll try that as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
  var id= x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  if id="247"
   {
       // print what ever u want
   }
}
```